# Is there a way to do command+a to highlight all text on a page with Rselenium? Or another way to highlight all text on a page?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

maybe with the sendkeystoactiveelement function like this?

sendKeysToActiveElement(
  list(key = 'command_meta', "U+0074")
)

U+0074 is the UTF code for lower case "a"

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this article from zevross.com](http://zevross.com/blog/2015/05/19/scrape-website-data-with-the-new-r-package-rvest/) of interest. It posts the following code as a "sneak preview" on the page

```
# Sneak preview of code for interacting with a web page with RSelenium
# a proper blog post with explanation will follow.

library(RSelenium)
# make sure you have the server
checkForServer()

# use default server 
startServer()
remDr<-remoteDriver$new()


# send request to server
url<-"https://programs.iowadnr.gov/animalfeedingoperations/FacilitySearch.aspx?Page=0"
remDr$open(silent = TRUE) #opens a browser
remDr$navigate(url)


# identify search button and click
searchID<-'//*[@id="ctl00_foPageContent_SearchButton"]'
webElem<-remDr$findElement(value = searchID)
webElem$clickElement()

# identify the table
tableID<-'//*[@id="ctl00_foPageContent_Panel1"]/div[2]/table'
webElem<-remDr$findElement(value = tableID)

doc<-htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])

tabledat<-readHTMLTable(doc)[[17]]
tabledat[,]<-lapply(tabledat[,],
    function(x) gsub("ÃÂ", "", as.character(x)))
tabledat<-tabledat[-nrow(tabledat),-1]
# go to next page
nextID<-'//*[@id="ctl00_foPageContent_FacilitySearchRepeater_ctl11_PagePlus1"]'
webElem<-remDr$findElement(value = nextID)
webElem$clickElement()
```

and this code as a function for extracting the data (which is subsequently mapped):

```
# FUNCTION from help for chartr 
capwords<-function(s, strict = FALSE) {
  cap<-function(s) paste(toupper(substring(s, 1, 1)),
        {s<-substring(s, 2); if(strict) tolower(s) else s},
        sep = "", collapse = " " )
    sapply(strsplit(s, split = " "),
        cap, USE.NAMES = !is.null(names(s)))
}
# ---------------------------------------


full<-mutate(geocodes, name=fnames) %>%
  mutate(category=ifelse(grepl("Winery", name), 1, 2)) %>%
  mutate(addressUse=gsub("Ny", "NY", capwords(gsub(", usa", "", address)))) %>%
  mutate(street=sapply(strsplit(addressUse, ","), "[[", 1)) %>%
  mutate(city=sapply(strsplit(addressUse, ","), "[[", 2)) %>%
  filter(!grepl('Interlaken|Ithaca|Aurora|Seneca Falls', street)) %>%
  select(name, street, city, category, lat, lon)

head(full)
```

[This article by Jim Plante](https://thescreenshotguy.wordpress.com/2016/02/13/navigating-scraping-job-sites-rvest-rselenium/) and [this one also by John Harrison](http://johndharrison.blogspot.ie/2014/03/rselenium-package.html) are worth a look also.

Comment: This doesn't help. I want to be able to send a hotkey(apple+a) to the webpage so that it highlights all the text.

Comment: @ghostrecon27 re-read the article by Jim Plante (and you evidently haven't read the one by John Harrison which outlines sending events to elements)

Comment: LOL neither of you two can answer my question. Like hammers to a screw you lack problem solving skills.

Comment: @ghostrecon27 I have 16.2k in rep; i have solved quite a few problems! You on the other hand, seem to lack many skills required for coding (including basic understanding of the problem!)

Comment: I have way more street rep then you and we both know that counts more.

Answer (score 1):

As Rachel noted you can use key presses as outlined in a number of links she gave. You can send key presses to an element (html tag). The `body` html tag can be used to send to the page:

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver()
appURL <- "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123833/is-there-a-way-to-do-commanda-to-highlight-all-text-on-a-page-with-rselenium-o/45123917#45123917"
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate(appURL)
# select the page 
bElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
# send key press to page
bElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "control", "a"))
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)

# cleanup
rm(rD)
gc()
```

The command key has unicode value of '\ue03d'. Checking this against the special keys in RSelenium:

```
sapply(selKeys, function(x) identical(x, '\ue03d'))
```

shows that the command key is referenced as `command_meta` so in MAC (untested) you could use:

```
bElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "command_meta", "a"))
```

in the above.

Comment: are you THE John Harrison from the blogspot? Excellent... :)

Comment: Again not what I am looking for. Imagine someone opens a browser and goes to a website and simply presses command+a. I don't want to scrape css elements-- that simply won't work for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: This is how you "simply" goto a website and press command + a using selenium. You are not "scraping" css elements.